# Make each event have unique variable for multiple quantity switches (Hard to topic)

Tags: javascript

This is quite difficult to title as my JS is basic at best. If you look at my example you see what I'm trying to do. I've got the events working on all elements now but I just don't know how to make the currentValue variable unique. Would this need an array?

Or can I make the currentValue variable unique to each function if that makes sense.

```js
const minus = document.querySelectorAll(".qty__btn--decrease");
const add = document.querySelectorAll(".qty__btn--increase");

let currentValue = 1;

minus.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', minusSelection);
});

add.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', addSelection);
});

function minusSelection(event) {
  if (currentValue != 1) {
    currentValue -= 1;
  }
  document.getElementById('qty').innerHTML = currentValue;
}

function addSelection(event) {
  currentValue += 1;
  document.getElementById('qty').innerHTML = currentValue;
}
```

```html
<div class="spares-results__price-section">
  <span class="spares-results__price">£5.00</span>

  <div class="qty">
    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--decrease">
        <span class="qty__symbol">-</span>
    </button>

    <span class="qty__amount">x<span id="qty">1</span></span>

    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--increase">
        <span class="qty__symbol">+</span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <!-- qty -->
</div>
<!-- price-section -->

<div class="spares-results__price-section">
  <span class="spares-results__price">£5.00</span>

  <div class="qty">
    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--decrease">
        <span class="qty__symbol">-</span>
    </button>

    <span class="qty__amount">x<span id="qty">1</span></span>

    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--increase">
        <span class="qty__symbol">+</span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <!-- qty -->
</div>
<!-- price-section -->
```

Comment: Pen here if that helps. https://codepen.io/qwerty-design/pen/YzOXgPX?editors=1010

Comment: SO has Stack Snippet, you don't need codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a variable, just use the contents of the `<span>` in the same div as the plus or minus button.

```js
const minus = document.querySelectorAll(".qty__btn--decrease");
const add = document.querySelectorAll(".qty__btn--increase");

minus.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', minusSelection);
});

add.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', addSelection);
});

function minusSelection(event) {
  let qty = event.target.closest(".qty").querySelector(".qty__amount span");
  let currentValue = parseInt(qty.innerHTML);
  if (currentValue != 1) {
    currentValue -= 1;
  }
  qty.innerHTML = currentValue;
}

function addSelection(event) {
  let qty = event.target.closest(".qty").querySelector(".qty__amount span");
  let currentValue = parseInt(qty.innerHTML);
  currentValue += 1;
  qty.innerHTML = currentValue;
}
```

```html
<div class="spares-results__price-section">
  <span class="spares-results__price">£5.00</span>

  <div class="qty">
    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--decrease">
        <span class="qty__symbol">-</span>
    </button>

    <span class="qty__amount">x<span>1</span></span>

    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--increase">
        <span class="qty__symbol">+</span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <!-- qty -->
</div>
<!-- price-section -->

<div class="spares-results__price-section">
  <span class="spares-results__price">£5.00</span>

  <div class="qty">
    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--decrease">
        <span class="qty__symbol">-</span>
    </button>

    <span class="qty__amount">x<span>1</span></span>

    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--increase">
        <span class="qty__symbol">+</span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <!-- qty -->
</div>
<!-- price-section -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you select all the sections with class equal to `spares-results__price-section` and fire event to the elements inside each.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.spares-results__price-section');

sections.forEach(section => {
  const minus = section.querySelector(".qty__btn--decrease");
  const add = section.querySelector(".qty__btn--increase");
  const amount = section.querySelector("#qty");
  
  add.addEventListener('click', addSelection);
  
  minus.addEventListener('click', minusSelection);  

  function minusSelection(event) {
    let value = +amount.textContent;
    if (value != 1) {
      value -= 1;
    }
    amount.textContent = value;
  }

  function addSelection(event) {
    let value = +amount.textContent;
    value += 1;
    amount.textContent = value;
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="spares-results__price-section">
  <span class="spares-results__price">£5.00</span>

  <div class="qty">
    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--decrease">
        <span class="qty__symbol">-</span>
    </button>

    <span class="qty__amount">x<span id="qty">1</span></span>

    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--increase">
        <span class="qty__symbol">+</span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <!-- qty -->
</div>
<!-- price-section -->

<div class="spares-results__price-section">
  <span class="spares-results__price">£5.00</span>

  <div class="qty">
    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--decrease">
        <span class="qty__symbol">-</span>
    </button>

    <span class="qty__amount">x<span id="qty">1</span></span>

    <button type="button" class="qty__btn qty__btn--increase">
        <span class="qty__symbol">+</span>
    </button>

  </div>
  <!-- qty -->
</div>
<!-- price-section -->
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mina I’ll put this into action tomorrow and report back if I run into any issues